# Forgot washer when after building a desk

Tags: wooden-furniture, desk, washer

I just finish building a desk. I already drilled holes prematurely (not deep, the table top isnt pre-drilled) and force my screw to fully go in.
It includes `washers` that is meant to be between the table top and legs but I totally forgot about it!

Should I take it apart to put in the washers? If so, would I run the risk of having the screw not being able to screw tightly (with/without the washer)

The washer is about the 50% of the hole depth.

[image: the table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The washers really really need to be in for this type of furniture.  They are there for side forces - meaning pushing the top of the desk forward, backward, left, or right.

Over time if you don't have washers the head of your screws will rub against the inside of the hole, or the end of the hole and make the hole bigger.  As holes get bigger the table will begin to sway and you will tell people you bought a janky table.

Answer (score 1):

Take out the screws, put the spacers in, replace the screws and tighten snug to firm, but not hard. See how it performs.